# PowerShell hash table key issues

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Maybe I am doing it wrong, but when I try and reference a hash table member using the key, I get no results, however when I filter a .GetEnumerator() output with the same key, I get a result.

This doesn't work:

```
$year = "2015"
$msol_year_members_table = @{}
foreach ($member in $(Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $(Get-MsolGroup | ?{ $_.DisplayName -eq $("Class of " + $year) }).ObjectId)) {
    $msol_year_members_table[$member.ObjectId] = $member
}

foreach ($mb in $(Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
    if ($msol_year_members_table.ContainsKey($($mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId))) {
        $msol_year_members_table[$($mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId)]
    }
}
```

Doing this works though:

```
foreach ($mb in $(Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
    if ($result = $msol_year_members_table.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.Name -eq $($mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId) }) {
        $result
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated - assuming it is some stupid mistake.

Comment: You are assigning to your hash table by `$member.ObjectId` key but then the working loop compares against `$_.Name`? Do you want that initial assignment loop to assign by `$member.Name`?

Comment: Take a look at [this article on using hash tables with powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx). I think you can accomplish whatever you're trying to do with the built in methods such as Get-Item, Add, Remove, etc.

Comment: Etan,
I am pretty sure $_.Name and $_.Key are the same - I just tested switching those two member names and it was working - you are looking at the working part of the code though, and not the portion I am having issues with.


Caleb, I just tested with the .Get_Item() function but I have the same issues and am still not getting any results :(

Comment: Have you considered doing `If($msol_year_members_table.keys -contains $mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId)`? I'm not sure what that comes across as, you may need to do `$mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId.ToString()`.

Comment: Just tried a few different syntax around your suggestion TheMadTechnician - none of them worked.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. Don't edit and add an answer into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a type mismatch between the keys and the test values?
When you use the `.containskey()` method, the argument value must be the same type as the key, but when you use the `.getenumerator()` method, the `-eq` test is going to try to coerce the .Name value and the test value to the same type for the operation:

```
$ht = @{
1 = 'one'
2 = 'two'
3 = 'three'
}

$ht['1']

$ht.GetEnumerator() |? { $_.name -eq '1'}

Name                           Value                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                      
1                              one
```

Comment: Thanks mate - seems like they were different types. I will post an update with what worked for me now.

Comment: Type mismatch was also my problem I used `($ht.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Name -eq '1' }).Name.GetType()` to determine the type of the hash table, and discovered that the hash table was using `[int32]` but my lookup value was `[uint32]`.  They aren't kidding when they say the types must match exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code - just in case it helps anyone, I used it to assign address book policies for dir sync'd groups to Office 365 mailboxes:

```
# Years to be processed
$years = @("2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022","2023","2024","2025","2026","2027")

# Loop through each year and retrieve the members for the groups
$msol_year_members_table = @{}
foreach ($year in $years) {
    foreach ($member in $(Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $(Get-MsolGroup | ?{ $_.DisplayName -eq $("Class of " + $year) }).ObjectId)) {
        $key = $member.ObjectId.ToString()
        $msol_year_members_table[$key] = $member
    }
}

# Loop through the mailboxes and set the mailbox poilicies for matching members
foreach ($mb in $(Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {
    $key = $mb.ExternalDirectoryObjectId.ToString()
    if ($msol_year_members_table.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $alias = $msol_year_members_table[$key].Alias; $alias_split = $alias.Split(".")
        $year = $alias_split[$alias_split.Length-1)]
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $alias -AddressBookPolicy $("Class of " + $year + " ABP")
    }
}
```